# Caliburn Micro and Windsor Castle Boostraper { No component for supporting the service }

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, caliburn.micro, bootstrapper

Hi I try use Windosor Castle with Caliburn Micro. Until now I use only MEF.

I founf this Castle Boostraper : https://gist.github.com/1127914

I added this calls to my project and modified App.xaml file:

```
<Application x:Class="Chroma_Configer.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:Bootstraper="clr-namespace:Chroma_Configer.Bootstraper">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Bootstraper:CastleBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />

                <Style x:Key="MainView_FontBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I create ShellView (WPF) and ShellViewModel:

```
public interface IShellViewModel
{

}


public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive,
    IShellViewModel
{

}
```

When I run I get this error:

> ```
> {"No component for supporting the service Chroma_Configer.ViewModels.IShellViewModel was found"}
> ```

I am  beginer in Windsor Castle I know that he work something like this:

```
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddComponent("JsonUtil", typeof(IShellViewModel), typeof(ShellViewModel));

        var shell = container.Resolve<IShellViewModel>();
```

In MEF I user attribute **[Export]** and **[Import].** Can me anybody hel me with this issue?

Another question is that I have some tool class:

```
public interface ITooll{}

public class Tool:ITool{}
```

and I would like import this in ShellViewModel class.

How can I do it with with CastleBoostraper?

Answer (score 2):

You need to register your view models and views in the container. The older Windsor version worked based on attributes, but on latest version you can do this with the fluent API or even bulk register based on some convention:

```
public class Bootstrapper : Bootstrapper<IShellViewModel>
{
    protected override IServiceLocator CreateContainer()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer();
        var adapter = new WindsorAdapter(_container);
        _container.Register(Component.For<ITool>().ImplementedBy<Tool>().LifeStyle.Transient);

        return adapter;
    }
}
```

You can also create Installers that will register types in the container so your Bootstrapper code will not end up with a lot of registration code:

```
public class ShellRegistration : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<ITool>().ImplementedBy<Tool>().LifeStyle.Transient);
        //Register other types
    }
}
```

And call it in the bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper : Bootstrapper<IShellViewModel>
{
    protected override IServiceLocator CreateContainer()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer();
        var adapter = new WindsorAdapter(_container);
        _container.Install(FromAssembly.This());

        return adapter;
    }
}
```

Check the Silverlight [sample application](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Silvertlight_Sample_App_Customer_contact_manager.ashx) I have created to find out how to work with Castle Windsor.

You can get instances of your dependencies using Constructor Injection or Property Injection something inline with this:

```
public class ShellViewModel
{
    public ShellViewModel(IMyDependency dependency)
    {
       //you'll get an instance of the class implementing IMyDependency
       //Logger property will be injected after construction
    }

    public ILog Logger
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```